# Code doesn't make sense -- two conditionals within PHP try

Tags: php

I have inherited an application that is not doing what it's supposed to do. I have isolated the problem to the database not being properly attached. The programmer wrote this function that seemingly is suppose to evaluate whether the database is attached, calling the "attachPaymentDatabase()" function to attach it if it's not.

```
function attachPaymentDatabaseIfNotDoneAlready()
{
global $db;
global $hasPaymentDatabaseAttached;
// Determine if we have attached the payment tables, and if not, add them.
$hasPaymentDatabaseAttached = false;
try { 
    // this new way should work the best-- looking for PAY.
    $alldb = queryall($db, "PRAGMA database_list;");
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($alldb); $i++)
        {
        $alldb[$i] = array_change_key_case($alldb[$i], CASE_LOWER);
        if (strtolower($alldb[$i]['name']) == 'pay')
            {
            debugEmail("condition 1 worked.");
            $hasPaymentDatabaseAttached = true;
            break;
            }
        }
    // if its name changed this will also work
    if (!$hasPaymentDatabaseAttached)
        {
        $r = @$db->querySingle("SELECT * FROM PAY_PARAMETER;"); 

        $hasPaymentDatabaseAttached = true;
        debugEmail("condition 2 worked.");
        }
    } 
catch(Exception $e) 
    { 
    }
if (!$hasPaymentDatabaseAttached)
    {
    debugEmail("nothing worked.");
    attachPaymentDatabase();
    }
}
```

I have written a debugEmail() function that emails me a defined message with a timestamp as used above. When executing the code from the application, I can see that "condition 2 worked." is being called one second before "nothing worked.".

I don't understand how this can be. If debugEmail("condition 2 worked."); is executing, then so should too $hasPaymentDatabaseAttached = true; in which case this should not execute:

```
    if (!$hasPaymentDatabaseAttached)
    {
    debugEmail("nothing worked.");
    attachPaymentDatabase();
    }
```

But it clearly is.

What is going on here?!?!?!?

Comment: It must be your mistake while debugging (testing wrong version, debugging on wrong host).

Comment: By the sound of it, it's being executed twice asynchronously through AJAX or something, because the code's doing what it's supposed to do. Remove that `@` sign to see if it suppresses any useful debug information. Other than that, it just looks like nonsense.

Comment: Nice idea @ShadowScripter. Maybe he should add some random variable `$function_call_id = mt_rand();` before try-catch, and send that variable value in e-mails.

Comment: That does sound like a prudent debug solution @Kamil. I'm still trying to figure out what the hell this code would ever be used for. It's like looking at the dead sea scrolls, except this is just nonsense :3

Answer (score 0):

No it shouldn't, because `$hasPaymentDatabaseAttached` is set to `true` in the first condition. In still nonsense at all, but it works as described.